# Different Results for Butterworth Filter in R and Python

Tags: python, r, smoothing, butterworth

I tried to run the same filter on the same data in R and Python and I got different results, below are the codes.
Can anyone tell me why does that happen and how do you solve it?

Python code:

```
from scipy import signal 
>>> fc = 0.05  # Cutoff frequency normal
>>> N = 1  # Filter order
>>> b, a = signal.butter(N, fc)
>>> print b, a 
[ 0.07295966  0.07295966] [ 1.         -0.85408069]
>>> data_in = [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 100, 101, 5]
>>> signal.filtfilt(b, a, data_in) 
array([-17.64249874, -13.92903176, -10.61891211,  -7.66701305,
        -5.03713838,  -2.70112003,  -1.19904652,  -1.65272747,  -4.06100815])
```

R code:

```
> library(signal)
> data_in<-c(1,2,4,5,7,8,100,101,5)
> N<-1 #order
> fc<-0.05 #cutoff frequency
> (b2<-butter(N,fc)) #the filter
$b
[1] 0.07295966 0.07295966

$a
[1]  1.0000000 -0.8540807

attr(,"class")
[1] "Arma"
> filtfilt(b2$b,b2$a,data_in)
[1]  6.142885  7.162141  8.303857  9.559103 10.921776 12.388452 13.397369 12.814425 10.637551
```

Can anyone understand why there's a difference here?

Answer (score 2):

After using this function on python instead of the original one, I received almost identical values.

```
signal.filtfilt(b,a,data_in,padtype = 'odd', padlen=3*(max(len(b),len(a))-1))
```